# AJAX call to GAE datastore

Tags: ajax, json, google-app-engine

What i want to do is to get some data from the Google App Engine datastore , via AJAX to my web page..And to do that I have something like :

```
$.getJSON('/orders/'+restaurant+'/.json', function(data)
```

and at that link, I expose some JSON...

My question is how can I make this to be more secure, because anyone with a little coding knowledge can use that link for he's purposes and to use my JSON info...

I was thinking that maybe I should encript that data or something...

Thnaks

Comment: Just encrypting things won't be enough.  What happens if a user tries a different restaurant.  What authorization method do you have in place to restrict the scope of what a user can access.

Comment: so the idea is that to the page using the AJAX call from above, only a user will have access (lets say the restaurant owner)...and the way to restrict him to not accessing pages that belong to other restaurants will be done by using cookies :)

Comment: Personally I wouldn't rely just on cookies.  I would have a formal authorization system in place, that checks the given principal (user identity) actually has permissions to read/update/delete etc....

Comment: How you might do this will depend on the framework(s)/language used.  (I have implemented quite sophisticated authentication and authorization policies use repoze.who and repoze.what on appengine).  So it is all do-able ;-)

Comment: can you give me a link to that?  will using that solve this concern that I have?

Comment: also i worked in python :)

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/repoze.what/1.0.9 and you can also find repoze.who in PyPI.  I am not specifically suggesting this package, I don't know you real requirements, nor what stack (webapp2, flask, pyramid ....) pyramid has repoze.who/what functionality built in. I would so some research in this area before embarking on the app.